# Отделения строки на числа С++

Tags: c++

У меня на вводе есть строка: "12:10:22", к примеру. Мне нужно строку разбить на 3 числа, для дальнейших операций. Исходя из примера должно получиться : первое число - 12, второе - 10, третье - 22.

Answer (score 3):

Если без защиты от дурака (т.е. строка **гарантированно** такого формата), то можно

```
int a,b,c;
char d;
istringstream s("12:10:15");
s >> a >> d >> b >> d >> c;
```

См. https://ideone.com/BN12Af

Comment: Еще один вопрос, как это можно реализовать так, чтобы пользователь вводил строку(без проверки на дурака).

Comment: `string st; cin >> st; istringstream s(st);`